# include bundles to project asp.net project

Tags: asp.net

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
                        "~/Scripts/signalr/jquery.signalR.js",
                        "~/Scripts/inputFileUpload.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.js",

                        "~/Scripts/MyScript.js",
                        "~/Scripts/queue.js",
                        "~/Scripts/mutation-summary.js",
                        "~/Scripts/tree_mirror.js"));
```

I have bundle ~/bundles/jquery , how to include this bundle to my csproj file so that I can push this bundle to server

Answer (score 0):

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

Use this in your razor view.

To register, you need to call the register method of BundleConfig.cs, like:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using this in my razor view but how could I send this bundles to server , how to include this bundle to my csproj file

Comment: Use BundleConfig.cs file. Please refer http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/scriptbundle-mvc